# Disable up and down arrow

Tags: javascript

I have this data field for input

[image]

And it does show a data selector plugin which works fine with the keyboard.

But I want to disable the up and down arrows. Could you guide me how?

Also need when date filed is clicked that it open date picker or when the user clicks on calendar icon
Thanks.

Code:

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="date"ng-model="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="date" style="width:180px" id="date" ng-required="true">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:auto">
                                    <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="date"ng-model="client.dateofbirth" class="form-control"  placeholder="Data de nascimento" style="width:180px" id="dateofbirth" ng-required="true">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:auto">
                                <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

the calendar icon also shows me down not in the correct place...
I want when I click on the textbox it opens the calendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // not working  

    $('#date').datepicker(
        {
            allowInputToggle: true

        });
```

Comment: Are you using html input date type?  If so, see how it looks using other browsers.  I generally tend to use UI libraries for date selection to ensure consistent UI between different browsers.

Comment: Post you html and javascript then we can help you better.

Comment: i have a datepicker from http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

however when i click the textbox or the icon it should open the datepicker

they said to use this code but its not working

 $('#dateofbirth').datepicker(
            {
                allowInputToggle: true

            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, it looks like the input has `type="number"`, but I am not sure why there is a dropdown arrow there. You can remove the up and down arrows using CSS. I always add this snippet in my main CSS/SASS file.

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
input[type="number"] { 
    -moz-appearance: test-field; 
}
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

<sub>Source: [Turn Off Number Input Spinners | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/)</sub>